# Check for multiple results in one URL path variable

Tags: php

How exactly should I modify this in order to check not only for 'Just-One-More-Step' but also others such as 'Thank-You-For-Registering'?

```
$url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    if (false == strpos($url,'Just-One-More-Step')) { echo '<div class="sideCourse"><a href="/Courses/Free-NLP-Training-Course/Signup-For-Free-NLP-Course/">Sign Up Now For FREE NLP Training Course</a></div>'; } else { echo ''; }
```

I thought it may have just been to add it like:

```
if (false == strpos($url,'Just-One-More-Step','Thank-You-For-Registering'))
```

but doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strpos` doesn't take multiple strings like that, you'll need to check for them separately...

```
if (false == strpos($url,'Just-One-More-Step') && false == strpos($url,'Thank-You-For-Registering')) { ... }
```